# Matlab: locate a string in txt and read it into a number

Tags: regex, matlab

I have an input file like this:

```
number of elements = 4
number of nodes = 6
number of fixed points = 2
number of forces = 1
young = 2.0E8
poiss = 0.2
thickness = 0.002

node group
1 2 6
2 3 4
2 4 5
2 5 6
```

And I use this to read the file

```
fid = fopen(input_file); 
tline = fgetl(fid);
line_number = 1;
while ischar(tline)
# this will locate the string, and find the number
    if ~isempty(strfind(tline,'number of elements'))
        NELEM = str2double(regexp(tline, '\d+', 'match')); 
    end
    if ~isempty(strfind(tline,'young'))
        YOUNG = str2double(regexp(tline, '\d+', 'match')); 
    end
    line_number=line_number+1;
    tline = fgetl(fid);     
end
fclose(fid);
```

The first works fine, however, for the second, `YOUNG`, the output is actually `[2 0 8]`(original number is `2e8`) The regexp turns the string into an `array`.
And for `poiss`, it read as `[0,2]`.

How can I turn the string into the original number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression needs to match floating point numbers with exponents, try changing `'\d+'` to

```
'[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][0-9]+)?'
```

This then matches numbers with an optional decimal point and exponent. For example:

```
str2double(regexp('young = 2.0E8', '[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][0-9]+)?', 'match'))
```

gives `200000000`.

Comment: I made a workaround like `temp = regexp(tline, '[=]', 'split');YOUNG = str2double(temp(2));` but my approach is really ugly.